# Java: Algorithm to match a string with unknown characters

Tags: java, regex, string, algorithm, matching

I have data stored in a database.
Database has 3 columns:
2 columns containing 6-character numeric strings (matching),
1 column contains the result

User can input 2 strings, I have to create an algorithm to match strings and get the result.

The allowed values ​​are numbers from 0 to 9, *, X and Y

---

```
EXAMPLE:

match1    match2      RESULT

123456    123*56      A
1234X8    123*X8      b
1*4567    1*5435      c
345**7    ******      d
12454X    12X124      E
123X5Y    123Y12      F
```

- Represents any possible value
  X and Y represent any value but different from themselves

---

if user insert:

```
123456 , 123756 ----> result are A

123498 , 123198 ----> result are B

123456 , 123412 ----> no results......because to obtain "F"....y 
                      have to be equals from inputs and 6!=4
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), asking us to write the program for you and suggestions are off-topic.

Comment: Could you explain how you determine the result values?

Comment: I need know if users have a possible algorithm to resolve this question

Comment: the result value is determined by a match from input strings and the database data....

Comment: One way is to create `RegEx` for each element of match and just run a linear loop and confirm that if input matches the `RegEx` of both elements of a pair and return corresponding answer.

Comment: yes, but matching element in database is dynamic and created by users....i will have to create a particular regular exp dynamically...

Comment: You are not saying if there is a match order. The same tuple of input string can have more then one match, so ordering matches is important.

Comment: if the string has more than a match you can obtain more than a result

Comment: The constraints are well defined, but have you tried coding yet? Are you expecting someone to code for you a complete answer?

Comment: I was just looking for an idea to develop the algorithm in the most elegant way possible ... of course I will develop it.

Comment: I added an idea for a simple algorithm, shown below.

Answer (score 0):

You can request the results directly with SQL.

The query is somewhat stupid, but it will do the job (inner query extracts the characters, outer query does the matching):

```
SELECT
   o.r
FROM (
   SELECT
      SUBSTR(t.match1, 1, 1) l1,
      SUBSTR(t.match1, 2, 1) l2,
      SUBSTR(t.match1, 3, 1) l3,
      SUBSTR(t.match1, 4, 1) l4,
      SUBSTR(t.match1, 5, 1) l5,
      SUBSTR(t.match1, 6, 1) l6,
      SUBSTR(t.match2, 1, 1) r1,
      SUBSTR(t.match2, 2, 1) r2,
      SUBSTR(t.match1, 3, 1) r3,
      SUBSTR(t.match1, 4, 1) r4,
      SUBSTR(t.match1, 5, 1) r5,
      SUBSTR(t.match1, 6, 1) r6,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT1, 1, 1) i11,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT1, 2, 1) i12,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT1, 3, 1) i13,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT1, 4, 1) i14,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT1, 5, 1) i15,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT1, 6, 1) i16,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT2, 1, 1) i21,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT2, 2, 1) i22,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT2, 3, 1) i23,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT2, 4, 1) i24,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT2, 5, 1) i25,
      SUBSTR(:INPUT2, 6, 1) i26,
      result r
   FROM
      table t
) o
WHERE
   (o.l1 = '*' OR o.l1 = o.i11) AND
   (o.l2 = '*' OR o.l2 = o.i12) AND
   (o.l3 = '*' OR o.l3 = o.i13) AND
   (o.l4 = '*' OR o.l4 = o.i14) AND
   (o.l5 = '*' OR o.l5 = o.i15) AND
   (o.l6 = '*' OR o.l6 = o.i16) AND
   (o.r1 = '*' OR o.r1 = o.i21) AND
   (o.r2 = '*' OR o.r2 = o.i22) AND
   (o.r3 = '*' OR o.r3 = o.i23) AND
   (o.r4 = '*' OR o.r4 = o.i24) AND
   (o.r5 = '*' OR o.r5 = o.i25) AND
   (o.r6 = '*' OR o.r6 = o.i26)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way ... so it was simple. You have to test the X and Y characters too. X represents any value but must be the same for all positions, but must be different from Y